# JPA attribute Override

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Can we override attribute to stop versionning in the subclass given it is used in the super i am using eclipse link.

```
Class A {
@Version 
int a;
}

Class B extends A
{
//a is used as a normal integer not a version.
}
```

if it is not possible can we override the version Field a to be transient in B and remove it from B table.

Comment: So you don't want JPA to use locking on B or is it that you don't want JPA controlling the field value?  Also since you mention B has its own table, it looks like you are using table per class - any reason why you don't just make B its own separate entity?

Comment: actually i have a master mapped super class that contain many policies and fields that used over all the system . class B must inherit everything from A without the version and i don't want to make another super entity that don't contain Version and inherit it by A.

Answer (score 1):

Versions seem to be considered fundamental to the entity, much like the ID does, so do not have a way to be overridden by subclasses.  What you could do is mark it as using field locking on the 'a' attribute by using the @OptimisticLocking annotation and specify the selectedColumns:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_optimisticlocking.htm
This would allow you to control the value used.  In A you might define a preupdate method that increments the value, while in B you can override the logic that increments it.  This will still allow optimistic lock exceptions to occur when another transaction changes the value 'a' value, but it makes it an application controlled step.

Comment: ok , so no way to stop version. but is there a way to make the version field transient in the child entity(B)

Comment: Making the field transient is the same as stopping versioning. You might try mapping the B entity through an orm.xml and marking it as metadata-complete.  If it works, it would require mapping every attribute in A+B.  I don't know how the metadata-complete works with MappedSuperclass